# How to set the title attribute of an element with not just a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set the title attribute of an element with some html. For eg:

```
<div id="element"></div>

$("#element").title = $("#menu");
```

where

```
<div id="menu"> 
   <a href="www.website.com">Link</a>
</div>
```

This does not render the menu in the title. Can this be done?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen, but I doubt it's possible.  What you expect to happen?

Comment: @recursive I want that whatever html I write in the menu div, should be rendered in the title

Comment: @infantDev The native `title` attribute/property is just for displaying plain text. If you want more control over the content and display, you'll probably have to look into using a custom "*tooltip*" -- another positioned element that appears on hover. Example: [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

Comment: @infantDev: Your use of `title` threw me off, because what you are trying to accomplish is not related to it.  See my answer.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Actually I am using the tooltip from jquery ui, and the content of the tooltip is picked from the title property of the element. That is why I wanted to set the title property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then NO, you cannot display HTML using the title attribute. Depending on what you are trying to do, you better find and use a jQuery tooltip or menu plugin. The [jQuery UI library](http://jqueryui.com/) has both.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** like

```
var title = $("#menu a:first").attr('href');
$("#element").attr('title',title);
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ndB6R/)**

Comment: hmmm... quite alike mine, why attr instead of prop?

Comment: @Sergio I think `title` is an `attribute` not `property` See http://api.jquery.com/attr/  and you will find **$( "#greatphoto" ).attr( "title", "Photo by Kelly Clark" );**

Comment: @Rohan Actually I wanted a generic solution for any html I put on the menu div, it might contain more than a link

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert the html contents of one element into another, you can use this.

```
$("#element").html($("#menu").html());
```

BTW, this doesn't deal with `title` at all.

Comment: But OP needs something different, not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var html_string = $("#menu a:first").prop('href');
$("#element").prop('title', html_string  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set html inside an attribute, but it will not display as renderable html.

```
 $("#element").attr("title", $("#menu").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var val = "<p>This is my new title</p>"
document.getElementById('element').setAttribute("title",val);
```